# Adding SSL support for elmah controller in elmah.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah.mvc

I wanted to require SSL for the Elmah controller in Elmah.MVC package. Has anybody already done this?
As of now I can secure it by requiring authorization but I would want elmah log data returned only over SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the ELMAH controller and add the following attribute:

```
[RequireHttps]
```

Example:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Elmah.Mvc
{
    [Authorize]
    [RequireHttps]
    public class ElmahController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string resource)
        {
            /* Adapted by Alexander Beletsky */
            return new ElmahResult();
        }

        public ActionResult Detail(string resource)
        {
            /* Adapted by Alexander Beletsky */
            return new ElmahResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Source code for the ELMAH controller taken from [GitHub project](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc/blob/master/src/Elmah.Mvc/ElmahController.cs)

Comment: yup, thanks, I was wondering if someone had extended ELMAH configuration to enable Https.

Comment: I don't think anyone has specifically done that, but glad this little fix worked out for you!